# Threadlocal remove?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-local

When using a `ThreadLocal` should I always call `remove()` when I am done or when I do `set` the old value is replaced anyway so `remove` is redundant?

Answer (score 19):

Because `ThreadLocal` has `Map` of `currentThread` and `value`, Now if you don't remove the value in the thread which was using it then it will create a memory leak.

> You should always call **remove** because **ThreadLocal** class puts values  from the **Thread** Class defined by  **ThreadLocal.Values localValues;** This will also cause to hold reference of Thread and associated objects.

From the source code of `ThreadLocal`

> **the value will be set to null and the underlying entry will still be present.**

Comment: You mean without `remove` it will not be GCed?

Comment: It is not about value it is about `Thread` which has reference in `ThreadLocal` if you don't call remove it will never get GCed.

Comment: This answer is now outdated. The current implementation of ThreadLocal has a per-thread map of values. From JavaDoc: "after a thread goes away, all of its copies of thread-local instances are subject to garbage collection".

Comment: how about thread-pool? If a thread is reused, old thread local will be reused? Will App server clear all thread locals before putting a thread in a pool?

Answer (score 15):

`set` always replaces the old value.

This is true for

- Calendar.set() and Date.set()
- BitSet.set()
- List.set()
- setters

> You mean without remove it will not be GCed?

It will not be removed until the thread dies.  It won't disappear on you without you calling  remove()

Whether this is a memory leak or not depends on your program.  You would have to create lots of threads with large thread local objects which you didn't need for some reason for it to matter. e.g. 1000 threads with a 1 KB object could waste up to 1 MB, but this suggest a design issue if you are doing this sort of thing.

---

The only place you might get a memory leak is.

```
for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
    // don't subclass Thread.
    new Thread() {
        // this is somewhat pointless as you are defining a ThreadLocal per thread.
        final ThreadLocal<Object> tlObject = new ThreadLocal<Object>() {
        };

        public void run() {
            tlObject.set(new byte[8 * 1024 * 1024]);
        }
    }.start();
    Thread.sleep(1);
    if (i % 1000 == 0) {
        System.gc();
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

with `-verbosegc` prints.

```
[Full GC 213548K->49484K(3832192K), 0.0334194 secs]
39000
[GC 2786060K->82412K(3836864K), 0.0132035 secs]
[GC 2815569K->107052K(3836544K), 0.0212252 secs]
[GC 2836162K->131628K(3837824K), 0.0199268 secs]
[GC 2867613K->156204K(3837568K), 0.0209828 secs]
[GC 2886894K->180780K(3838272K), 0.0191244 secs]
[GC 2911942K->205356K(3838080K), 0.0187482 secs]
[GC 421535K->229932K(3838208K), 0.0192605 secs]
[Full GC 229932K->49484K(3838208K), 0.0344509 secs]
40000
```

Note: the size after a full GC is the same `49484K`

In the above case you will have a ThreadLocal which refers to the Thread which refers to the ThreadLocal. However, as the Thread is dead it doesn't cause a memory leak becasue it becomes a regard object i.e. when A -> B and B -> A

I ran the above example in a loop for a couple of minutes and the GC levels moved around alot but the minimum size was still small.

Comment: @Jim Good question, have added an answer.

Comment: Peter, leak can happen on extended ThreadLocals since the thread is going to keep a reference to. Think of undeploying and dynamic classloaders.

Comment: The ThreadLocal doesn't actually hold the object. The object is held in a ThreadLocalMap in the Thread itself where the ThreadLocal object is the key. When the Thread stops, all its thread local objects can become unreachable (unless they are held elsewhere)

Comment: ThreadLocal is not `final` but the only time I have seen it subclassed is to define an initialValue. If this is defined in the Thread's context you have a problem, but sub-classing Thread is generally considered a bad idea.

Comment: Yeah, initalValue is the culprit usually but not necessarily. The point is that threads can be orthogonal and if they are not: calling services or responding to RMI would create a instance in the Thread map. I'd say left/forgotten ThreadLocals are #1 offender when it comes to class loader leaks.

Comment: It tried constructing a sub-classed ThreadLocal with a reference to the Thread itself. But I couldn't produce a memory leak.

Comment: @bestsss I will have to take your word for it :)

Comment: The leak doesn't work like that, just long lived threads keep stale references to objects that should have been long gone. If the thread dies everything is well and fine but threadpools/designated threads can live until the end of the process while many others objects/classloaders can by dynamically loaded/unloaded.

Comment: The entry in the ThreadLocalMap extends WeakReference<ThreadLocal> and the value has a HARD ref in the ThreadLocalMap.Entry[] -- since the value will have a reference to the classloader and the classloader to the ThreadLocal --> #1 leak offender. You need dynamic classloading to exploit it fully, though.

Answer (score 9):

**No**, it is not required to call *remove()* everytime instead of *set()*

If you fear memory leaks, here is what the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) says

> Each thread holds an implicit reference to its copy of a thread-local variable as long as the thread is alive and the ThreadLocal instance is accessible; after a thread goes away, all of its copies of thread-local instances are subject to garbage collection (unless other references to these copies exist).

Thus not calling *remove()* will not prevent a thread-local instance to be properly garbage collected, and will not cause any memory leak by nature.

You can also take a look to ThreadLocal implementation, which use [WeakReferences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) for this "implicit reference" mechanism

**But** beware of consistency with thread pools

Using *set()* method only with a thread pool, you might prefer to *remove()* a ThreadLocal instance, instead of overriding it in another "work unit" using the same thread.
Because you might want to avoid the situation where, for some reason, the set method is not invoked, and your ThreadLocal remains attached to a context/treatment it does not belong.

Answer (score 4):

`set`: Sets the current thread's copy of this thread-local variable to the specified value.

Meaning whatever was in that memory location, will now be overwritten by what you passed through `set`

Answer (score 3):

If the variable you're trying to `remove` will be always `set` in next executions of the thread, I wouldn't worry about removing it. `set` will overwrite its value.

But if you're setting that variable only in some circusmtances (for instance, when treating only a specific kind of requests), removing it might be convenient so that it doesn't stay around when, for instance, the thread is put back into the pool.

Answer (score 1):

I will make it simple:
If you extend the ThreadLocal for any reason use `remove()`. On vanilla ThreadLocal use `set(null)`.
Basically not using `ThreadLocal.remove()` on an *extended* ThreadLocal can lead to memory leaks (ClassLoader ones most likely)

If you need more details why, post a comment.

Comment: I don't understand your differentiation of `set(null)` and `remove`. Should I call `set(null)` before calling `set`?Why would this cause a leak?

Comment: @bestsss interesting distinction.

Comment: @Jim, not removing the object via either `set(null)` or `remove()` and the thread keeps going would be the thing causing the leak. There is absolutely no need to call set prior to set(xxx).

Comment: @irreputable, yeah I never extend ThreadLocals and keep non-bootstap/system classloder loaded classes in there unless in try/finally{remove}. Link to [my guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11826736/554431) to avoid leaks.

Comment: @bestsss recent jdk's ThreadLocalMap references keys weakly, so it should be fine. are you worried about other ThreadLocal impls?

Answer (score 0):

If the thread is done the `threadLocalMap` will be done with the thread. You do not need to remove it. But if the thread is used recycling you need to remove the value of `threadLocalMap`.