# Use of ThreadFactory in java

Tags: java, multithreading, threadgroup

The definition of **ThreadFactory** interface as per [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html) is **An object that creates new threads on demand. Using thread factories removes hardwiring of calls to new Thread, enabling applications to use special thread subclasses, priorities, etc.**

I have not been able to understand the term **hardwiring of calls to new Thread** , also I am not able to understand the proper use and purpose of **ThreadFactory**

Kindly please explain.
Thanks.

Comment: This is a classic example of a [Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)). Nothing _to_ understand except that.

Comment: Refer this question [ThreadFactory usage in Java][1] it contains some helpful examples.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179733/threadfactory-usage-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have not been able to understand the term hardwiring of calls to new
>   Thread

Basically you don't have to tightly couple caller with thread object instead you can deledate to ThreadFactory. One advantage of this i can think is lets say you want to mock the thread call for unit testing, you can achieve it easily

> also I am not able to understand the proper use and purpose of
>   ThreadFactory

See [http://javahowto.blogspot.in/2011/11/why-use-threadfactory.html](http://Why%20to%20use%20thread%20factory)

Answer (score 3):

Read about *Dependency Injection* and *Inversion of Control*.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

Suppose I write a library, and my library needs to create a thread.  Suppose you have a large, complex application program, and you would like to use my library, but your application has strict policies about managing threads, and all of its threads must be created by calling a special application-specific module.

If my library calls Thread.new(), then you can't use it because it bypasses your policy, but if my library lets you give me a ThreadFactory, and my library uses your ThreadFactory to create its thread, then the problem is solved:  You can give me a ThreadFactory that creates the thread by calling on your application's thread-management module.