# Thread and ThreadFactory

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton, threadpool, executorservice

I am just bit confused with Threads and ThreadFactory. So I am raising this question. 
 My intention is to set a name for each thread that is running so that it will be easy for me to track which Thread is running and interrupted in logs.With ThreadFactory I saw its is possible.

```
String someName="fileName"; // Inside first file 
...........................
.........................

Executors.newFixedThreadPool(30, new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat(someName).build()); //in singleton class
```

When the  Thread start doing some task I am getting the Thread name that is currently in progress using `Thread.currentThread().getName()` and this is fetching me the value as someName. My question is since I am give the name someName in newFixedThreadPool will the same name persist for all the thread in this pool . What will happen if I call `ExecutorService` (this is in singleton class) once again and I assign `someName="fileName2"`

Comment: This post will help you.
[ThreadFactory usage in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179733/threadfactory-usage-in-java)

Comment: You want to know how ThreadFactoryBuilder works but it's not a built in class. I assume you mean the Guava class of that name? What does the source for this class say it does?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about the Guava class `ThreadFactoryBuilder` the [setNameFormat](https://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release05/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ThreadFactoryBuilder.html#setNameFormat(java.lang.String)) method is documented as

> nameFormat - a String.format(String, Object...)-compatible format String, to which a unique integer (0, 1, etc.) will be supplied as the single parameter. This integer will be unique to the built instance of the ThreadFactory and will be assigned sequentially.

This means you have to include in the format name, where you want the counter included.  If you haven't done this, you have effectively stated you want all threads to have the same name.

> My question is since I am give the name someName in newFixedThreadPool will the same name persist for all the thread in this pool .

My guess is the format is not set correctly so all your threads will have the same name.

> What will happen if I call ExecutorService (this is in singleton class) once again and I assign someName="fileName2"

The new thread pool will have all it's thread called "fileName2"

Obviously, you don't want to be creating thread pools repeatedly.  The whole point of a thread pool is for it to be reusable.

Also you probably don't want the thread pool size to be 30. It is more likely you want it to be the number of CPUs or possibly double depending on your use case.

Comment: In that case can you tell me how to format name for individual thread in single pool . I do not want to create a new pool everytime . This is achieved by making ExecutorService as static variable. But If I want to give task for individual thread and give a name for it how can I do it. I have used Thread.currentThread().setName() and getName to know the thread which is running. Is there some other way to do it.

Comment: @Rashmi I would use setName and reset it when finished.