# Parallel Executing of an AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

In parallel executing of an asynctask, I find out 2 ways:

First one using `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`:

```
myTask.executeOnExecutor ( AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR );
```

Second one using `AsyncTaskCompat.executeParallel`:

```
AsyncTask asyncTaskTest = new myTask();
AsyncTaskCompat.executeParallel ( asyncTaskTest , null );
```

Is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

If the device runs on Honeycomp or above, then there is no difference.

Below Api 11, the tasks will execute serially from api 1 to (exlusive) DONUT and run back in parellel from DONUT to Honeycomp.

So:

**API 1 - 3:** serially on a single background thread

**API 4 - 11:** parallel with pool of threads

**API 12- x:** uses `executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);`

Depending on your minimum API level, you could just use `executeOnExecutor()` directly from `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTaskCompat.executeParallel ( asyncTaskTest , null ); has been deprecated found in this [Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/os/AsyncTaskCompat.html).

Using ThreadPoolExecutor you can achieve Parallel Execution since you can pass ThreadFactory which helps is creation of Object [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3179909/1562755)

Since the later has more robust functionality compared to the first. It is better to move with the later and the [Developer blocks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/os/AsyncTaskCompat.html) also suggests so.